# Trying to integrate a popup using highslide into an image mapped with imagemapster

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, highslide, imagemapster

So I am using imagemapster on a page I've created to change regions of an image map on mouse hover. I would like for a pop up to occur on click and intended to use highslide to execute this, however, I'm struggling with how to implement this. My current code looks something like this:

```
<head>  

<script language="javascript" src="include/imagemapster/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script> 

<!-- Highslide -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/highslide/highslide-with-gallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="include/highslide/highslide.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="highslide/highslide-ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!-- End Highslide -->

</head>
<body>

    <img src="img/closed.jpg" id="leoweb" usemap="#leoweb" border="0">

<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#leoweb').mapster({
    singleSelect : true,
    render_highlight : { altImage : 'img/open.jpg' },
    mapKey: 'hex',
    fill : true, altImage : 'img/open.jpg',
    fillOpacity : 1,
});
});

</script>

    <map name="leoweb" id="leoweb">
    <area hex="1" class="highslide" href="onclick="return hs.expand(this)"

        title="" style="float:right; margin: 0 0 10px 15px">
    <img src="img/hex1.png"  alt=""
        style="width: 107px;height:120px;" />" shape="poly" coords=" 463,73, 363,74, 305,160, 363,258, 462,255, 513,168, 465,76" />
    <area hex="2" href="#" shape="poly" coords=" 579,196, 521,292, 578,384, 675,388, 733,294, 683,200, 585,198" />
    <area hex="3" href="#" shape="poly" coords=" 243,202, 138,202, 86,293, 133,379, 245,382, 295,293, 251,206, 245,206" />
    <area hex="4" href="#" shape="poly" coords=" 353,330, 304,419, 361,513, 461,508, 513,413, 461,324, 354,328" />
    <area hex="5" href="#" shape="poly" coords=" 229,450, 142,451, 83,542, 133,638, 239,636, 296,538, 245,452, 239,450, 235,450, 233,450" />
    <area hex="6" href="#" shape="poly" coords=" 453,575, 355,574, 303,664, 351,764, 460,765, 515,672, 459,577, 457,576" />
    <area hex="7" href="#" shape="poly" coords=" 573,453, 521,550, 574,638, 681,638, 737,550, 685,450, 577,452" />
</map>
</div>
```

Now that bit about trying to add the highline code

```
class="highslide" href="onclick="return hs.expand(this)"

        title="" style="float:right; margin: 0 0 10px 15px">
    <img src="img/hex1.png"  alt=""
        style="width: 107px;height:120px;" />"
```

Into the image map was a long shot, but I tried it as it was the most logical href insertion point I could think of. It obviously did not work. Are any of you familiar enough with highline and imagemapster to help with this, or at least have some clue about a possible solution? Thanks.

Comment: Oh also, jquery is included, though I forgot to mention that in the code, this is not the problem.

Comment: First, it's "Highslide," not "highline." But I think this demo page might help you out: http://highslide.com/examples/image-map.html